# The node /hbase-unsecure is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am going to try hbase in local, I did start one zk server,when I try to create a table like this:

```
create 'table', 'col'
```

error:

```
ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase-unsecure is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

and:
I think maybe it has something to do with the **hbase-site.xml** 
here is :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:////Users/zhaiyi/Documents/apache-hadoop/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/Users/zhaiyi/Documents/zookeeper/server1/zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha </value>
  </property>
  <property>
        <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
        <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

It doesn`t work, ask for help!! thanks!!

ps: **hbase-1.1.2**  &  **hadoop-2.6.3**

Answer (score 1):

When the HBase master is started it should create the `/hbase-unsecure` znode in ZooKeeper.  [This page](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/HBaseUseCases) is a bit out of date, but describes how HBase uses ZK.  The first thing you should try is restarting the hbase master to see if that helps.

HBase provides a shell [zkcli](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#trouble.tools.builtin.zkcli) you can use to run zookeeper commands.  For instance `./hbase zkcli -server host:port ls /` should show you what znodes exist at the top-level.  In your case it is not clear where your ZK server is, but the default port for ZK is `2181`.  The `/hbase-unsecure` znode that the error refers to should be listed in response to that command.

Note also, depending on the vendor if the hbase cluster was ever started in *secure* mode, the created znode will be `/hbase-secure`.

Comment: thanks for answer, I checked that there is no node /hbase-unsecure in zk. I start a standalone zk server.HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false. I want to kown how hbase connect with zk and I think that is where I was wrong